# GL ERROR - after deleteUnusedTextures() glerror (0x502) on Android webView

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm trying to make a game based on Javascript and Jquery, what I've done is adapt in Android webview. I tried it on the gingerbread or similar versions and works perfectly.
The problem comes when you test it on an Android device with Jelly Bean, I seem to duplicate the images or something. I have searched and is a bit limited information found about this error.

***GL ERROR - after deleteUnusedTextures() glerror (0x502) ***

Basically my code in Android Web View is: Any idea what could be my mistake?:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.game); 
this.setContentView(R.layout.game);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
setTitle("Juego");
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview01);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.url.com/index.php");
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Note: Do not put the javascript code as it is too long

Answer (score 0):

I put hardwareAcceleration = "false" in the android manifiest and the problem for me disappears.

Comment: I need to have hardwareAcceleration = "true" for some transitions.